# Update an item in Directus CMS with PHP

Tags: php, directus

I have tried to update an item following the Directus documentation, but I can't update the record, it always returns

> { "error" : { "code" : 6, "message" : "Method Not Allowed" } }

My PHP code is:

```
$url = 'https://cms.domain.com/public/name-of-project/items/products/1?access_token=TOKEN';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(['category'=>43]));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you already solved the issue but you need to set the method to POST:

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

Otherwise a GET request is made, which seems not to be supported.